# Як правильно писати ім'я американського фізика Ка́ку?

Tags: власні-назви, іноземні-імена, spelling

У Вікіпедії [вказано](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BE_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83) два варіанти написання - Мітіо та Мічіо:

> Мітіо (Мічіо) Каку (англ. Michio Kaku, яп. ミチオ・カク) — американський
>   науковець у галузі теоретичної фізики та екології. Обіймає посаду
>   професора теоретичної фізики у міському коледжі та університеті міста
>   Нью-Йорк. Автор багатьох книг та науково-популярних статей.
>   Найвідоміші серед них — Фізика Неможливого (2008), Фізика Майбутнього
>   (2011) та Майбутнє Розуму (2014), які також входять до числа
>   бестселерів.

Українською одна з книг, [Фізика майбутнього](http://www.yakaboo.ua/fizika-majbutn-ogo.html), вийшла авторства **Мічіо Кайку**, а в [цій статті](http://life.pravda.com.ua/society/2013/05/29/129982/) він знову **Мітіо Каку**.

Comment: У цій статті пропонують цей ієрогліф передавати українською як "чі" https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://papers.univ.kiev.ua/1/shidni_movy_ta_literatury/articles/vakhnenko-shpigunov-ranscription-and-transliteration-of-the-japanese-pr_16650.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiIibm52J_SAhUmGZoKHSJIBDgQFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNFk2-avcBGc1S_ePWzGwTPmh9OD9w&sig2=d-XbfxJMU0K-joz0v6dMRg

Comment: Російська транскрипція Поліванова, створена у 1917 році, тут використовує "ті". (з тої самої статті у посиланні).

Comment: @Artemix Вибачте за прискіпливість, але це не ієрогліфи. Це символи катакани - https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0, японської складової абетки для іншомовних слів.

Comment: До речі, в книзі він **Кайку**, а не **Каку**. В чому тут причина?

Comment: **Кайку** – це там у них якась страшна помилка.

Comment: А, могли цілеспрямовано викривити прізвище для милозвучности, аби не було схоже на «каку» ))) Дитячі комплекси...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не занурюючися глибоко в фонетику й фонолоґію японської мови, слід зазначити, що в імені цього вченого вживається склад ち ~ チ [ʨi], який вимовляється з дуже м’яким, палатальним приголосним та звучить як щось середнє між українськими ***ті*** та ***чі***, трохи шепеляво.

В сучасній стандартній транслітерації японської засобами латинського алфавіту, що зветься «rōmaji» (*римські знаки*), у найрозповсюдженішому її [варіанті Гепберна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.93.D0.B5.D0.BF.D0.B1.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BD.D0.B0) цей склад записується як ***chi***, саме так він і пишеться при вживанні японських слів, зокрема імен, в англійській, це й є джерелом  ***Мічіо***, та от тільки українській ***ч*** [tʂ] – це твердий ретрофлексний приголосний, який не відповідає японській вимові ち ~ チ [ʨi].

Найрозповсюдженіша система запису японської мови засобами кирилиці зветься [системою Поліванова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.96.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2), була розроблена в 1917, опублікована в 1930. За цією системою склад ち ~ チ [ʨi] записується як ***ти*** (з російською вимовою ***и***), це й є джерелом запису імені вченого українською як ***Мітіо***.

Зверніть увагу, що в українській немає стандарту запису японської за допомоги української кирилки. Зважаючи на те, що система Поліванова є дуже поширеною, я схиляюся до використання саме її з адаптацією до української (так звана [система Бондаренка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#.D0.91.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BA.D0.BE)), тобто із заміною ***и*** > ***і***, ***ё*** > ***йо/ьо*** та ***г*** > ***ґ***, а отже найкраще по-нашому писати саме ***Мітіо***. Це виглядає набагато простішим, ніж транслітерація аж через 4 етапи: японська > система Гепберна > англійський правопис > українська. Застосовуючи адаптовану систему Поліванова ми маємо лише 2 етапи: японська > адаптована система Поліванова. Зверніть увагу, при передачі звуків однієї мови писемністю иншої втрати неминучі.

Comment: Оскільки йдеться не про норму, а про варіанти, не можу погодитися, що полівановка (й похідні від неї) ліпша до застосування, хоча вона давно офіційна для російської. Система Коваленка: http://nndiuvi.org.ua/images/book/29.pdf, на мій погляд, краща для украЇнської.

Comment: @Ukurainajin - Чим же ж краща система Коваленка? Голосні з макронами (ā, ӯ, ē, ō) дуже легко набирати? «Ю» з макроном (ю̄)??.. Вживання _ї_ для запису [i] ­– це нормально? «/iː/ ([iː]) записується як _ії_ для уникнення плутанини _ī_ та _ї_» – це нормально? Де тут послідовність? Я тут бачу лише люту ідіосинкразію. Як ви зі мною не згодні, візьміть і напишіть власну відповідь, тільки вже тоді покажіть переваги системи Коваленка над иншими чотирма системами транслітерації японської українською. Конкретики дайте. І, до речи, ваш нік ви пишете Гепбернівською системою, чому ж не коваленківкою? )))

Comment: По-перше, у Коваленка транскрипція, а не транслітерація, як У Поліванова, тому показувати довготу голосних макронами необов'язково, якщо не треба, у Поліванова це взагалі не регламентується. Це знімає і ваше питання про «ї». По-друге, немає сенсу тягнути з російської передачу звуків з し через «с». Ви ж знаєте, що це давня тема для холіварів. У Коваленка все послідовно і враховано давні недоліки полівановки. Українською це виходить краще.

Comment: @Ukurainajin - І яка ж то транскрипція, фонетична чи фонематична? Там усе намішано: «Сполучення /ei/, що може вимовлятися як e [e:] або eй [ei̯], передається уніфіковано — eй. У випадку [e.i] пишеться еї» – тут фонематика, а тут «приголосний /ɴ/ записуємо як **м** перед /m, b, p/» – фонетика. Це послідовно? Просто купа правил та химерних написань, які збивають з пантелику й затуманюють японське написання каною. Як би не писали кирилкою, це все – умовності, просто одні умовності зручніші за инші, от коваленківські – незручні. Все, мені тут додати більше нема чого.